# Kendo MVVM Template Dropdown with HTML

Tags: kendo-mvvm, kendo-template

I have a kendo template in which I am binding a kendo DropDownList.  I am having trouble getting HTML to show in the text of the dropdown.

```js
$(function() {
    var field = {
        DisplayValue : "Blue",
        OptionListDetails : [
            { Text : "<span style=\"color:#F00\">Red</span>", Value : "Red" },
            { Text : "<span style=\"color:#0F0\">Green</span>", Value : "Green" },
            { Text : "<span style=\"color:#00F\">Blue</span>", Value : "Blue" }
        ]};
  
    var fieldObservable = kendo.observable(field);
    var controlTemplate = kendo.template($("#dropdownTemplate").html());
    var view = new kendo.View(controlTemplate(fieldObservable), { model: fieldObservable, wrap: false });
    view.render($("#renderPlace"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="dropdownTemplate">
  <select data-bind="value: DisplayValue, source: OptionListDetails" data-role="dropdownlist" data-text-field="Text" data-value-field="Value" >
  </select>
</script>
<div id="renderPlace">
```

Is there some sort of binding I can pass to get the HTML to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I was right that the solution involved additional bindings.  I had to create another template and bind the `data-template` and `data-value-template` properties of the DropDownList.

```js
$(function() {
    var field = {
        DisplayValue : "Blue",
        OptionListDetails : [
            { Text : "<span style=\"color:#F00\">Red</span>", Value : "Red" },
            { Text : "<span style=\"color:#0F0\">Green</span>", Value : "Green" },
            { Text : "<span style=\"color:#00F\">Blue</span>", Value : "Blue" }
        ]};
  
    var fieldObservable = kendo.observable(field);
    var controlTemplate = kendo.template($("#dropdownTemplate").html());
    var view = new kendo.View(controlTemplate(fieldObservable), { model: fieldObservable, wrap: false });
    view.render($("#renderPlace"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl"> #=Text# </script>
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="dropdownTemplate">
  <select data-bind="value: DisplayValue, source: OptionListDetails" data-role="dropdownlist" data-text-field="Text" data-value-field="Value" data-value-primitive="true" data-template="template" data-value-template="template" >
  </select>
</script>
<div id="renderPlace">
```